# Basic Differential Geometry Problem 2

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

This problem is part of a practice problem set for my exam, and I'm having trouble with it.

A particle is moving on the plane equipped with polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$. The coordinates of the particle satisfy differential equations $$\frac{dr(t)}{dt}=r^{2}(t) + 1, \frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=1$$
(where t is the time).

(a) Find all possible trajectories $(r(t),\phi(t))$ of the particle starting at t = 0 at the origin; draw the trajectories on the plane. Check that every point of the plane, except the origin, lies on exactly one such trajectory.

(b) For every trajectory ?nd its tangent line at an arbitrary point $(r,\phi)$ of the plane lying on it; pay special attention to the tangent line at the origin $(r = 0, \phi$ is undefined$)$.

(c) Rewrite all trajectories in the Cartesian coordinates $(x(t),y(t))$ where $x = r\cos\phi, y = r\sin\phi$.

(d) Fix an arbitrary point $(a,b)$ of the plane and consider the trajectory of the particle passing through it at the moment $t$ of time: $x(t) = a, y(t) = b$. Find the velocity $(\frac{dx(t)}{dt},\frac{dy(t)}{dt})$ of the particle at the moment $t$.

(e) Explain how to solve Problem $(d)$ directly from equation that the particle satisfies, not using explicit formulas for the trajectory $(x(s),y(s))$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dot{r}= 1+r^2,\, \dot{\theta}= 1,$$

Divide

$$ \dfrac{dr}{d\theta} = 1+r^2$$

Integrate, and with BC

$$ r= \tan ( \theta+ \alpha)$$

Cartesiian coords

$$ x= r\cdot \cos \theta , \,  y= r\cdot \sin \theta $$

Hope you can take it further with differentiation.